# Should reference-type members ever be marked readonly in a disposable class?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, idisposable

**PROBLEM DESCRIPTION**

1. I have a class that implements `IDisposable` using accepted practices. See `FooClass` in the example below. I am using a `string` field for simplicity; try to imagine that this class has a legitimate reason for implementing `IDisposable`.
2. `FooClass` initializes its own reference-type dependency, `FooMember` (not ideal, but assume it's necessary).
3. `FooMember` is a read-only field.
4. Normally I would set reference-type members to `null` during disposal. `FooMember` is read-only so I cannot. See the commented line in the example below.
5. Per standards, I have instructed the garbage collector to suppress finalization of `FooClass` using `GC.SuppressFinalize` (see below).

**QUESTIONS**

1. Will the garbage collector leave `"foo"` in memory after an instance of `FooClass` is disposed and out of scope?
2. Should reference-type members ever be marked `readonly` in a disposable class?

**EXAMPLE**

```
public FooClass : IDisposable
{
    public FooClass()
    {
        FooMember = "foo";
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (IsDisposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsDisposed = true;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            // The line below won't compile because FooMember is read-only.
            // FooMember = null;
        }
    }

    private readonly string FooMember;
    private bool IsDisposed = false;
}
```

Comment: as long as your reference types are managed types you don't need to handle them in the disposing process.

Comment: @Zohar: I have seen that said in other answers on the subject. I have also seen arguments to the contrary, though, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2280118/3187456). Regarding my first question, do you know if `GC.SuppressFinalize` will cause `"foo"` to remain in memory?

Comment: Setting members to null is a contract violation.  Not yours but hiding the bug in the client code is not a good idea, it just make it harder for him to find the leak.  Only valid consideration is that your member object *might* be collected earlier because it is a younger generation.  But that will never be the case for an initonly member.  So don't do it.

Comment: When `Foo` is collected by the `GC` if there are no live references to `FooMember`outside `Foo`then it will be eligible for collection too, setting it to `null` does not really help in any way.

Comment: @InBetween - Is that true even when `GC.SuppressFinalize` has been invoked by `Dispose` (as in this example)?

Comment: Yes, why would it be any different? The finalizer is suppressed in the disposable pattern precisely because all the necessary job (release unmanaged resources) is already done when `Dispose()` is called; the only thing you do in the finalizer is call `Dispose(false)`.

Comment: @InBetween - Okay, all clear. Thanks, man. I'm just being paranoid about memory leaks.

Comment: @InBetween: Disposing an object does not make it eligible for garbage collection.  If a form has buttons to, e.g. open and close a connection, and if closing a connection clears a flag but doesn't null out the form's reference to the connection object, then the connection object and everything to which it holds a reference may remain ineligible for collection until a new connection is opened or the form itself is disposed.  If the objects to which the connection object holds references are large, that could be expensive.

Comment: @supercat where did I say that disposing an object makes it eligible for collection?

Comment: @InBetween: You said that nulling out `FooMember` doesn't help anything.  That's true in cases where the `FooClass` instance is eligible for GC, but it seemed as though you were presuming that would always be the case.

Comment: My understanding of commentary by @InBetween is that `GC.SuppressFinalize` does not actually change the behavior of the garbage collector with respect to the target class or its fields other than to make it ignore any user-declared finalizers. That is really what my question hinges upon because if, to the contrary, `GC.SuppressFinalize` will cause fields not to be garbage-collected, the answer to question 2 above is **NO**.

Comment: @supercat Yes I understand what you mean, the field is set to null in Dispose so it could be understood that I was implying that dispose and available for collection were equivalent. The key part was "if no external references to `FooMember` exist"; two self referencing objects will still be collected if they are not reachable in any other way, the GC is smart enough to detect cycles of this sort. That's what I meant and expressed rather poorly.